# Jmeter blob upload does not allow to Upload

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to record upload functionality from my web application. This Web page has telerik file explorer which as upload functionality if i run Jmeter and try to record it does not allow to upload , it does not give any error just the file keep on uploading with no progress. If i close jmeter it uploads perfectly.

I saw in FileUpload tab file as blob not sure if that is the problem or how it can be achieved using Jmeter.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try other tools for recording? Capturing the traffic using a tool like fiddler or charles then adding the parameter to your HTTP request manually might be another option.

Comment: Adding manually is the second option, once we are successful with recording using Jmeter. Do you think Jmeter recording is not good enough to handle this ?

Comment: I faced multiple cases where Jmeter was not able to record a transaction, there could many reasons why, cant say it is a Jmeter recording issue. I'm suggesting that you try other workarounds which will give you the expected correct results.

Comment: Try with MIME type as application/octet-stream

Comment: The problem i see is in FileUpload Tab in File Path it is capturing as "blob" instead of "Filename". Why it is capturing as blob i am not understanding, from where it will pick blob..ideally it picks filename from Jmeter/bin

Answer (score 0):

You should copy your file in jmeter/bin and upload the file in website from this folder